# nth-of-type acting like nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this html code:

```
 <div class="productWarp">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="productLine" ></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="productLine" ></div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
  .productWarp .productLine {
        background-color: #DFDDDD;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }


    .productWarp .productLine:nth-of-type(2)
    {
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
```

This choosing the second child of productWarp(first productLine) and not the second productLine,so it acting Exactly as nth-child selector

```
<div class="productWarp">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="productLine" ></div>//this one is choose
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="productLine" ></div>//this one should be choose
    </div>
```

any idea what wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:nth-of-type()` looks at an element's type, not its class. In this case, all your elements are of the type `div`, which is why `:nth-of-type()` works exactly the same as `:nth-child()`.

If you have only two `.productLine` elements, use the following selector to style your second one instead:

```
.productWarp .productLine ~ .productLine
{
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Otherwise you'll just have to go by `:nth-child()` indices, in this case `:nth-child(4)`, or override styles for subsequent `.productLine` elements by adding more rules repeating the `~ .productLine` part as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This take in consideration the clearing div.

```
.productWarp div.productLine:nth-of-type(4n)
```